# MySql date format error

Tags: mysql, sql

here `MAX(DATE_FORMAT(rental_date, '%d/%M/%Y')) & MAX(rental_date)` give different output (not in terms of format but in the actual dates)

For eg one gives `31/July/2005` and other gives `2005-08-22 20:03:46`  so here one is July and the other is August. Why is it so? is there any problem with the query?

```
SELECT customer_id, MAX(DATE_FORMAT(rental_date, '%d/%M/%Y')) AS Last_rental, MIN(DATE_FORMAT(rental_date, '%d/%M/%Y')) 
AS First_Rental, MAX(rental_date) AS last_R, MIN(rental_date) AS first_R FROM rental
GROUP BY customer_id
ORDER BY customer_id
```

Comment: Can you try - `DATE_FORMAT(MAX(rental_date), '%d/%M/%Y')`?

Comment: @SougataBose I don't know. Is there any problem with it?

Comment: show sample data and desired output for date.

Comment: The issue is that the output of `date_format` is a string. If you order the strings `'31...'` is "greater than" `'22...'` regardless of what follows those characters.

Comment: This almost seems too obvious :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the output of `date_format` is a string. If you order the strings `'31...'` is "greater than" `'22...'` regardless of what follows those characters.

It you want the latest date, but need it in a particular format, take the max first and then do the formatting:

`DATE_FORMAT(MAX(rental_date), '%d/%M/%Y')`

(As per Sougata Bose's comment.)

Answer (score 0):

try to use:

**from:**

```
DATE_FORMAT(rental_date, '%d/%M/%Y')
```

**to:**

```
DATE_FORMAT(Date(rental_date), '%d/%m/%Y')
```

**or the normal date format:**

```
DATE_FORMAT(DATE(rental_date),'%Y-%m-%d')
```